# this pointer in c++ maybe 0xffffffff

Tags: c++

After read *Inside the C++ Object Model*, I try to call member function from vptr.

I found the following situation by accident

gcc version 9.2.0 (tdm64-1)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Foo;
Foo* foo;

class FooBase
{
public:
    virtual void Bar1(){};
    virtual void Bar2(){};
};
class Foo : FooBase
{
public:
    void Bar1()
    {
        if (this == nullptr)
        {
            std::cout << "this == nullptr in Bar1" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "this == " << this << " in Bar1" << std::endl;
            std::cout << "foo == " << foo << " in Bar1" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Bar1" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo = new Foo;
    // std::cout << "foo == " << foo << " in main" << std::endl;

    int* vptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(foo);
    int* bar1_ptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(*vptr);

    typedef void (*Func1)();
    typedef void (*Func2)(Foo*);

    Func1 bar10 = (Func1)*bar1_ptr;
    Func2 bar11 = (Func2)*bar1_ptr;

    bar10(); // sometimes 'this == 0xffffffff in Bar1'
    bar11(nullptr); // this == nullptr in Bar1
    return 1;
}
```

When I comment `std::cout << "foo == " << foo << " in main" << std::endl;`

the output is

```
this == 0x96ae0 in Bar1
foo == 0x96ae0 in Bar1
Bar1
this == nullptr in Bar1
Bar1
```

But when I uncomment `std::cout << "foo == " << foo << " in main" << std::endl;`

the output is

```
foo == 0x1d6ae0 in main
this == 0xffffffff in Bar1
foo == 0x1d6ae0 in Bar1
Bar1
this == nullptr in Bar1
Bar1
```

Q1: Why this pointer has a default value `foo == this`?

Q2: Why this pointer was changed after uncomment?

Comment: What did you expect `this` to be?

Comment: Did you really mean to cast an int to an int* in the line that set bar1_ptr? doing so is only valid for systems where sizeof(int)==sizeof(int*).  Usually when one is doing this kind of internal accessing, a pointer type would be used where you have int.

Comment: This code has undefined behaviour all over the place; it's not meaningful to reason about it. Note also that a compiler is free to assume that `this` is never null, since the code would have undefined behaviour in that case. Some compilers warn about this pointless check.

Comment: It has been said that the book really should be called " Inside **a** C++ Object Model". It's misleading to assume that the model described in the book is the only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access Bar1 via Func1, this ends up being whatever was on the stack in the first arg's position.  It wasnt a default value - it just happened to be there from your previous calls.

No surprise that the stack can change with change to previous calls.

As you probably found out, calling a class member functions can be implemented as a regular function that takes a class pointer as an argument. In your compiler and case, it looks as though the following are equivalent.

```
foo->Bar1();
bar11(foo);
```

Comment: They are not equivalent, since `bar11(foo)` has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @molbdnilo it is undefined in the language, but becomes defined when all else that pertains - compiler, system, hardware, etc are defined and sufficiently constrained.  The OP has provided fairly strong evidence that it is equivalent in his specific environment.

Comment: @Abel Unless the toolchain documents that is defined, it is undefined (and gcc does not provide any well-definedness for this as far as I know). You can't tell from observation whether anything is undefined or not. Observation is – at best – an anecdote, which is only sligthly stronger  evidence than a Facebook rumour.